# Connecting uipagecontrol to my whole uicollectionview, not to the individual cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I have a UICollectionView (in a UIViewController) displaying 20 cells/images per page. I have set the UICollectionView's scroll direction to **Horizontal** and layout to **Flow**. I've enabled **Scrolling** and **Paging**. So when i have more then 20 cells/images i can swipe horizontally to page to the next lot of cells/images. **This works perfectly!**

**However**, what i would like to do now is add a way to show how many pages are available and which one i'm currently on. I assumed UIPageControl is the way to go, so I've placed it nicely underneath my UICollectionView.

**The Question is**: How do i connect the UIPageControl to my existing scrolling / paging UICollectionView **?**

Look forward to your responses.

Answer (score 0):

The collection view  (since it's a sort of scroll view) allows the vc to be a scroll view delegate.  Set the `delegate` to your vc, and implement `scrollViewDidScroll`.  Therein, compute the page by asking the collection view for `indexPathsOfVisibleCells`.  With any index path in the returned array, you can compute the current page with `indexPath.row / 20`.

Page control lets you set `currentPage` and `numberOfPages` as properties.  If I understand your setup correctly, numberOfPages == the datasource array count / 20.